# Powershell command to delete all files that do not exist in other folder

Tags: powershell, file-management

I have two folders, A and B which contain mostly similar file names, but some files are missing from `A`.

**A**
  | 2.txt
  | 10.txt
  | zxc.txt

**B**
  | 1.txt  // this should be deleted
  | 2.txt
  | 10.txt
  | asd.txt  // this should be deleted
  | asdfg.txt  // this should be deleted
  | zxc.txt

How can I delete all files from B that don't have a coresponding name with the same file in A? So, in the end B should have the same file names remaining as in A.

It doesn't really have to be powershell, I just need a way to bulk-remove the files on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried something? I'd do it by doing something like `$A=GCI -Path A:\ | select fullname,name; $B=GCI -Path B:\ | select fullname,name; if($B[$i].name) -notin $A.name){Remove-Item $B.fullname}`.

Comment: Note that the file names in A and B are the same, but the file contents are different (eg: think of version A and version B of those files, but I no longer need version B for those who no longer have a version A).

Comment: @flolilolilo Thanks, I'll try that, I have 0 experience with powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell there always is an alternative way.
With this initial tree (on ramdrive A:):

```
PS A:\> tree . /F
A:\
├───A
│       10.txt
│       2.txt
│       zxc.txt
│
└───B
        1.txt
        10.txt
        2.txt
        asd.txt
        asdfg.txt
        zxc.txt
```

This one liner outputs:

```
PS A:\> gci B|?{! (test-path ("A\$($_.Name)"))}|rm -whatif
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "A:\B\1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "A:\B\asd.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "A:\B\asdfg.txt".
```

The more verbose version (! equals not ):

```
Get-ChildItem B|Where-Object {! (Test-Path ("A\$($_.Name)") ) }|Remove-Item
```

No vars just piping ( on condition)

Comment: The second one says `Remove-Object` does not exist, the first one outputs "performing the operation" but doesn't actually remove the files.

Comment: @Cristy Sorry, it's `Remove-Item` and if you remove the `-Whatif` (a precaution) from the first it should do.

Answer (score 3):

As per @flolilolilo comment, this worked:

```
$A=GCI -Path ./A | select fullname,name;
$B=GCI -Path ./B | select fullname,name; 

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $B.Count ; $i++) {
  if($B[$i].name -notin $A.name){
    Remove-Item $B[$i].fullname
  }
}
```

I had to search for the `for` syntax in PowerShell,  so I hope it's correct. It worked in my case.

Comment: Glad I could help; and yes, you used `for` correctly.